# SQL Query to compare values from 2 tables and to show a third value from the second table

Tags: sql

I am relatively new to SQL coding and need some help.
I have table A where I have a field which holding a number. This number is an ID from Table B.
I need an expression to do the following:
from table A compare the number and find the id in table B with the same number. if there is a match, show the value of another field value from table B of the ID in B.
Example:
Table A:
stateRef=123456
Table B:
id=123456 (this is the value where table A is referring to) ; name=xyz (the name of field for id 123456)

Thanks.

Comment: This is called a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select tableB.[name] from tableB inner join tableA on tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

> `Update:`

```
SELECT DISTINCT n3.streamname as 'StreamName', n3.state, s1.name, n3.streambuildnumber, n3.streamclustername, n3.streamduration, n2.phasename, n2.phaseduration, n2.state, s1.id from sqladmin.statedef s1
inner join sqladmin.new1_4 n3  on n3.[state] = s1.id 
inner join sqladmin.new1_5 n2  on n2.[state] = s1.id 
WHERE n2.phaseparentstream = n3.dbid AND n2.state = s1.id AND n3.streambuildnumber = s1.id 
GROUP BY n3.streamname, n3.state, s1.name, n3.streambuildnumber, n3.streamclustername, n3.streamduration, n2.phasename, n2.phaseduration, n2.state, s1.id
```

Comment: This is the SQL query I now have:

Comment: This is the SQL query I now have: "SELECT DISTINCT
n3.streamname AS "StreamName",
s1.name from s1 inner join n3 on n3.state = s1.id AS "StreamState",
s1.name from s1 inner join n2 on n2.state = s1.id AS "PhaseState"
FROM
sqladmin.new1_4 n3,
sqladmin.statedef s1,
sqladmin.new1_5 n2
WHERE
n2.phaseparentstream = n3.dbid AND 
n2.state = s1.id AND 
n3.streambuildnumber = s1.id
GROUP BY
n3.streamname,
n3.state,
s1.name,
n3.streambuildnumber,
n3.streamclustername,
n3.streamduration,
n2.phasename,
n2.phaseduration,
n2.state,
s1.id"

Comment: But when trying to run it I am getting an error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try below query,

```
SELECT B.NAME
FROM B INNER JOIN A
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join to connect two or more tables .

Joins having different types . In order to improve ur skill in sql just practise joins well.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

For ur Question answer is use **inner join** :

```
SELECT B.Name 
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Cheers.